# On hover the sub menu is not staying as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

in my code when i try to hover the main menu then the sub menu should open and i can click the other link of sub menu as well.I have done almost everything but except when i try to hover the sub menu it is not showing.

I hover on menu i can see the sub-menu but when i try to go sub-menu it disappears

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".accounts").mouseenter(function() {
            $(".underdrop").slideDown();
        });
        $(".accounts").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".underdrop").slideUp();
        });

 }); 




.accounts{

display: inline-block;

position: relative;
}
.underdrop{
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left:250px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height:230px;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    display:none;

}

.underdrop::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 15px solid #4b968a;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 55px;
    transform: rotate(45deg );
    margin-top: -15.5px;
    z-index: 9999
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a6qqzywn/)

Comment: I'm on mobile and can't really test it now. But I guess the reason is the mouseleave function. Probably you might have to check if the mouse leaves to the sub menu and not close the main menu in this case. One could also think about closing the menu only when hovering the rest of the page. But this might be bad for the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update your `document.ready` function like this. i have checked in jsfiddle

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".accounts").mouseenter(function() {
            $(".underdrop").slideDown();
        });
        $(".underdrop").mouseleave(function() {
            $(".underdrop").slideUp();
        });

 });
```

check updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6qqzywn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,it's the answer i was looking for.May i know the logic please ?

Comment: in your jsfiddle demo you are sliding up submenu when leave the main menu so i remove   $(".accounts").mouseleave(function()$(".underdrop").slideUp();}); and i added code for event on mouse enter on submenu $(".underdrop").mouseleave(function() {$(".underdrop").slideUp(); }); in my jsfiddle so submenu will be opened after leave main menu and still opened and will be close on leave submenu..